# Table locking on update

Tags: sql-update, locking

I have the following SQL to update a table

```
update  table1 t1
inner join  tbl2 t2 on on t1.ForeignId = t2.id
set t1.Qty = T2.Qty
```

Please note that only t1 is updated. This SQL is ran inside transaction.

After this SQL, 
I try to drop the table outside transaction - 'Drop table if exists tbl2' 
This hangs and the table is locked

Is there any way to use this table to update another table within transaction  and I drop it afterwards before the transaction is committed?

Answer (score 0):

No obviously not, tbl2 is in active use as long as the transaction is not committed. You could work with a session-temp table holding a t2 copy, or just wait with the deleting until you're finished.